# How to set the position of the model matrix?

Tags: c++, glm-math

Let's say there is a model `model` matrix, let's call it "player".

```
model = glm::mat4(1.0);
```

The player may have had scale, rotate, and move effects applied to it.

```
model = glm::scale(...);
model = glm::rotate(...);
model = glm::translate(...);
```

Now I need to set a new position for this player, not relative to the player itself (which is what the translate method does), but relative to the "world", that is, relative to the origin of world coordinates <0, 0, 0>.

The solution that immediately comes to mind is the following:

```
model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(x, y, z));
```

The problem is that by replacing the `model` matrix with the `glm::mat4(1)` matrix, all previously applied scaling and rotation effects disappear.

Comment: Translate by `new_position - player_current_position` - this has the effect of moving the player to the origin and then moving to the new position.